# Adjectival form of "brown-nose"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How would you categorize an action that is characteristic of a brown-noser (somebody who tries too hard to impress)?

Comment: Please supply sample sentence for word request.

Comment: *brown-nosing* - it's a brown-nosing action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sycophantic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sycophantic) (MW)

> of, relating to, or characteristic of a sycophant: fawning, obsequious

as sycophant is a synonym of brown-noser, toady, bootlicker, etc.